# How to cancel an alertdialog?

Tags: android, dialog

I wanted to do a password alert box on an activity so once it has the correct answer it closes the dialog box but I cant seem to find a way when searching of how to close a dialog box the way I have coded it anyway.

Here is my code

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert1.setTitle("Password");
alert1.setMessage("Please enter your password below and press Ok.");

final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert1.setView(input);

alert1.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
        ((Global) Menu.this.getApplication()).setgPassword(value);
        ((Global) Menu.this.getApplication()).setgSiteId(strSavedMem1);
        LogIn();
    }
});

alert1.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});

alert1.show();
```

Is there a way to close this alertbox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check out this link of the Android documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DismissingADialog

There it is explained how can can cancel a Dialog.

Answer (score 7):

You can receive dialog instance in DialogInterface onClick method.

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                      alert1.setTitle("Password");
                      alert1.setMessage("Please enter your password below and press Ok.");
                      final EditText input = new EditText(this);
                      alert1.setView(input);
                      alert1.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                              String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
                              ((Global) Menu.this.getApplication()).setgPassword(value);
                              ((Global) Menu.this.getApplication()).setgSiteId(strSavedMem1);
                              LogIn();
                              alert1.dismiss();
                          }
                      });

                      alert1.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                              //System.exit(0);
                              alert1.cancel();
                          }
                      });
                      alert1.show();

                }
```

Comment: The method dismiss() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder

Comment: The method cancel() is also undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder

Comment: Create the dialog as an object, ie:
final AlertDialog dialog;
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog = alert.create();
and you can then call dialog.cancel();

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
 AlertDialog.Builder successfullyLogin = new Builder(
        YourActivity.this);
      successfullyLogin.setCancelable(false);
      successfullyLogin.setMessage("Successfully LoggedIn !");

      successfullyLogin.setPositiveButton("Ok",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
           int which) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         }
        });
      successfullyLogin.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the dialog to disappear when the user presses a button? If so, you don't have to do anything, it should be dismissed automatically (when the user presses any button).

Do you want the dialog to disappear on its own when the correct password has been entered? Then you will need to add a TextWatcher to the EditText field:

```
input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()....)
```

Callback functions in the TextWatcher will be called whenever the text changes, and you can there check whether the password is correct, and if it is, call

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don´t have to do anything.
As is said in the Android Documentation linked by anonymous:
"When the user touches any of the action buttons created with an AlertDialog.Builder, the system dismisses the dialog for you."
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DismissingADialog

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder Dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


Dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        Dialog.setCancelable(true);

      }});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a long time ago but I have a different solution from most of the other answers.

> In my case, I wanted to cancel the AlertDialog when a certain button inside my inflated view was clicked. Of course, this has nothing to do with setNegativeButton() or setPositiveButton() so I had no access to any alertdialog object.

**Here is how I solved this:**

At the point of showing your AlertDialog (`alertDialog.show()`), you can just store the `.show` object into a variable as shown below:

```
AlertDialog shower = alertDialog.show();
```

Once this is done, you can easily cancel your alertdialog by calling `shower.cancel()` anywhere within your AlertDialog scope.

I hope this helps. Merry coding!